# Mockk calls the method instead of mocking the dependency

Tags: kotlin, mockk

Hi I have the something similar in my production code. A simple method that will throw an exception:

```
class Production {

    fun doWork(): String {
        throw IllegalArgumentException()
    }
}
```

However, when I mock this `Production` class with Mockk, it runs the underlying `doWork()` method instead of mocking the method call:

```
import io.mockk.MockKAnnotations
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.impl.annotations.MockK
import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test

class Test {

    @MockK
    lateinit var production: Production

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this)
    }

    @Test
    fun test() {
        every { production.doWork() } returns "Str"

        assertEquals("Str", production.doWork())
    }
}
```

The test fails with `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`. Shouldn't Mockk be mocking this method call in `Production` class? I have a feeling that this could be a misunderstanding on my part coming from a Mockito background.

Comment: Please post a *complete* minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: Your test passes here. But of course, I had to add and guess a lot of imports, because you didn't post them. So the error is probably in the imports.

Comment: Interesting @JBNizet I've added the imports - it seems it was the version of Mockk I was using was not good. Version 1.3 had this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of current (Mockk [1.13.4](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/releases/tag/v1.13.4)), this is fixed/working as expected:

```kotlin
import io.mockk.MockKAnnotations
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.impl.annotations.MockK
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class Production {
    fun doWork(): String = throw IllegalArgumentException()
}

class Test {
    @MockK
    lateinit var production: Production

    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() = MockKAnnotations.init(this)

    @Test
    fun test() {
        every { production.doWork() } returns "Str"
        assertEquals("Str", production.doWork())
    }
}
```